# Remove text before the slash by replace () Method

Tags: javascript, replace

I have an input of this type, for example:

```
Guerre Stellari / Star Wars (1977)
```

the output should be:

```
Star Wars (1977)
```

how do I get it using the replace() method?

Comment: Why `replace`? `substring` is probably easier in this example

Comment: @NickA Yes, but I need to use replace

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
'Guerre Stellari / Star Wars (1977)'.replace(/.*?\/\s+/, '')
```

But easier would be:

```
'Guerre Stellari / Star Wars (1977)'.split(' / ')[1]
```

More reliable:

```
'Guerre Stellari / Good / Bad (1929)'.split('/').slice(1).join('/').trim()
```

Comment: What happens when the string is `Guerre Stellari / Good / Bad (1929)`?

Comment: @NisargShah same : var x = 'Guerre Stellari / Star Wars (1977)'.split('/'), z= x[0]; w = x[1], y = x[2]

Comment: @Danil You have fixed the first example, but the second one still returns the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method.

```js
var str = 'Guerre Stellari / Star Wars (1977)';

console.log(str.substring(str.indexOf('/') + 1).trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `/[^/]+$/`

The ^ in a group says "match all charters not in this group". So match all characters that are not slashes `/` all the way to the end of line $.

Here is a dry run of `/[^/]+$/` against  `"Guerre Stellari / Star Wars (1977)" .`
https://regex101.com/r/bSzRr7/1